# How to change Quote Item attributes after adding it to cart?

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, cart, addtocart, quoteitem

I want to change almost all the quote item attributes after adding it to care like name,price,sku and almost everything. As we have a requirement where at the runtime only we will decide this attributes.
But I want to do that at Item level only and not at the product level.
I have tried using the observer but there I was able to change the item price only using $item->setCustomPrice();
But when I do $item->setName("Custom Item Name"); this does not work and item name does not gets saved.
Can some one please tell me what is the thing I am doing wrong or is there any other way by which I can achieve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `sales_quote_item_set_product` and in **observer** file you can write below code to change the value.

```
$item = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem();
$item->setName("Your new value");
```